# how can we get the number of concurrent active streams in a cluster?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, network-programming, cluster-computing

I work with java sockets and I transfer data between nodes of the cluster, the trasfer can be tree braodcast (master sends data to some nodes and they send received data to the rest ), chain broadcast (master sends data to all the workers sequentially), shuffle (all the nodes exchange data simultaneouly)

the trasnfers are simply a stream between 2 nodes (master-worker or worker-worker) using java serverSocket and socket communication.

how can I determine the number of concurrent flows (active stream in the cluster) so I can schedule these flows and give every flow a part of the network

network bandwidth is 1 gb/s
socket buffer is 8192-byte

here is an [illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mud4.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best you will be able to do is to maintain your own data structure recording the "flows" and then count them.

The Java APIs don't provide a way to find or count all open sockets, or determine which ones are currently active.   It is probably not tractable even at the native code level.   And that is only within a single JVM: you presumably have multiple JVMs in your cluster.

Comment: yeah exactly we have multiple JVMs in the cluster, so you think there is no way to schedule network parts to the open sockets ?

Comment: I didn't say that.  What I said was that there is no way to **count** the sockets.  That's what you mean by *"get the number of ..."* isn't it?